# Find X items for a user that he has not bought

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a list of many users who have bought items. I would like to create negative samples, this means I want to show which items a user has not bought.
I select every user in my data frame and see which items they haven't bought.
I have already done this, but unfortunately this code is very slow.
How do I find which items a user has not bought?

```
d = {'userid': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
     'itemid': [715, 845, 98, 12324, 85, 715, 2112, 85, 2112, 852, 102]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df.head())
    
    # this is the test dataframe
   userid  itemid
0       0     715
1       0     845
2       0      98
3       1   12324
4       2      85

import random
testRatings = test
print(testRatings.head())
test_negative =  [[] for i in range(len(testRatings))]
for index , row in testRatings.iterrows(): 
  for n in range(20): # here I find 20 items that a user has not bought
    ra = random.randrange(item_max)
    IsRating = df.loc[(df['userid']==n)&(df['itemid']==ra)]
    if(IsRating.empty):
        test_negative[index].append(ra)
    # This list contains only 3 values not 20
    # As you can see 3 items that the user has not bought
    #                user 0        user 1
>>> test_megative = [[2112,85,852],[845, 98, 715],...]
    # This is the complete example list
>>> test_megative = [[2112,85,852],[845, 98, 715],[2112, 98, 715],
                     [85, 12324, 102], [715, 12324, 98]]
```

Comment: How looks expected output from sample data? What is in `test_negative` values? I think not like some values in list, but what exactly values from sample data.

Comment: @jezrael  Sorry and thank you for pointing this out! I have adjusted it, is this okay?

Comment: @jezrael Adjusted it again, had a small bug. Please note I only issued 3 items instead of 20 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the final result in a list, you can use the following code.
You first create a set of all the possible items you have in column `itemid`; then, for each `userid`, you subtract all the items he bought from `all_items`, thus obtaining a list of the items he didn't buy.

```
all_items = set(df['itemid'])
df.groupby('userid').apply(lambda x: list(all_items.difference(set(x['itemid']))))
# userid
# 0           [2112, 12324, 102, 852, 85]
# 1    [2112, 98, 102, 715, 845, 852, 85]
# 2      [2112, 98, 12324, 102, 845, 852]
# 3       [98, 12324, 102, 715, 845, 852]
# 4             [98, 12324, 715, 845, 85]
# dtype: object
```

---

**EDIT**

In order to have the results in the form `[[], [], ...]` and make sure that each `userid` has at most **3 random non-bought items**, use the following code instead

```
random.seed(123)   # for reproducibility
df.groupby('userid').apply(lambda x: random.sample(list(all_items.difference(set(x['itemid']))), 3)).tolist()
# [[2112, 102, 85],
#  [85, 715, 102],
#  [2112, 852, 102],
#  [845, 852, 102],
#  [715, 98, 845]]
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! Is it still possible to set how many items should be given out for example only 3 for every user?
and is it possible to write the list in the form `[[], [], ..] `?

Comment: For the second question, check out my updated answer. But I didn't understand your first question, I'm sorry

Comment: Thank you so much! I mean, for example, User 0 now has 5  items and User 1 has 7 items. But each should only receive 3 items, so it should look like this.`# 0 [2112, 12324, 102] # 1  [2112, 98, 102] #X [1,2,3]`

Comment: 3 items at random is ok?

Comment: Yes it would be ok

Comment: Your code is correct shows all items that a user has not bought and I would like only 3 random items that he has not bought

Comment: @Ella check out my edit, it should be ok now

Comment: Quick question, is there an option to remove this group by?
I need another place too, but the `test.shape [0] == len (list)`  should be there. Is that also possible? If I remove it like that then I always get a error `df.apply(lambda x: random.sample(list(all_items.difference(set(x['itemid']))), 3)).tolist()`

Comment: I'm sorry but such option doesn't come to mind